# PHP Dynamic Image Gallery using Bootstrap 4 flexbox

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, gallery

How can I dynamic below html in foreach loop? I've an images array I can echo one image per loop but I'm not sure how can I loop two images per loop?

```
  <div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
     <img src="1" class="img-fluid">
     <img src="2" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
     <img src="3" class="img-fluid">
     <img src="4" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
     <img src="5" class="img-fluid">
     <img src="6" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
     <img src="7" class="img-fluid">
     <img src="8" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
 </div>
```

This what I tried.

```
      <?php $images = get_field('image_gallery'); ?> 
       <?php if($images): ?>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
           <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?> 
             <div class="d-flex flex-column">


                 <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"> 
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?> " class='img-fluid' alt=""> 
                 </a> 
                <!-- This duplicates the image and need some break or continue statment -->
                  <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"> 
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" class='img-fluid' alt=""> 
                 </a>


           </div>           
          <?php endforeach; ?> 
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: So you want to output 2 images in each iteration (eg: image1 image2; image3 image4; etc...)?

Comment: can you print the $images?

Comment: Yes, but duplicate 
image1
image1
image2
image2 
and so on

Comment: Yes, @BrettGregson, 2 images in each iteration.

Comment: You can try `array_chunk` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code. May be it help you

```
<?php $images = get_field('image_gallery'); ?> 
       <?php if($images): ?>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
           <?php for ($i=0; $i < count($images); $i++) { ?> 
             <div class="d-flex flex-column">


                 <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="<?php echo $image[$i]['url']; ?>"> 
                    <img src="<?php echo $image[$i]['url']; ?> " class='img-fluid' alt=""> 
                 </a> 
                <!-- This duplicates the image and need some break or continue statment -->
                  <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="<?php echo $image[$i+1]['url']; ?>"> 
                    <img src="<?php echo $image[$i+1]['url']; ?>" class='img-fluid' alt=""> 
                 </a>


           </div>           
          <?php 
                    $i++;
                }
           ?> 
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop instead and iterate the loop every 2 images...

```
   <?php $images = get_field('image_gallery'); ?> 
       <?php if($images): ?>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
           <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i+=2){ ?> 
             <?php $image = $images[i];?>
             <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                  <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"> 
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?> " class='img-fluid' alt=""> 
                  </a> 
                  <?php if (!empty($images[i+1])) { ?>
                   <?php $nextImage = $images[i+1];?> 
                   <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="<?php echo $nextImage['url']; ?>"> 
                     <img src="<?php echo $nextImage['url']; ?>" class='img-fluid' alt=""> 
                   </a>
                 <?php } ?>
           </div>           
          <?php } ?> 
          </div>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Not worked! your code iterates only  second index value and the first  images src is blank.